# Sublime Text dirty search? Need some keywords to do research on

Tags: regex, search, text, full-text-search, sublimetext

If you have used Sublime Text, you probably know that if you open Command Palette <kbd>Ctrl | Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and start typing `he`, it'll bring all of the entries that have `h` and `e` with the same order but not necessarily adjacent. Like:

[image: sublime-text]

I'm looking for some keywords to look up how this is implemented but the only word I think I had heard of before is `Dirty look up` but the doesn't take me anywhere. Any term, keyword or resource on what this is called and/or how it's implemented is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `fuzzy searching` or `fuzzy matching`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some mechanism that:

- Splits the letters you provided
- Looks for upper case first
- Highlight in the words that have the largest amount of these characters
- If above is not found, highlight the first occurrence

Comment: This does not answer the question, and is incorrect in the details as well.

Comment: Oh, a Sublime Text developer? Please share your feedback then. Just downvoting is easy, isn't it?